# I want to see in the month of February datas from 20:00 to 08:00 the next morning

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to select data from a table using where clause.The scenario is here.I want to see in the month of February data from 20:00 to 08:00 the next morning.Here the field is datetime.
How can i select data?please reply

Comment: Show us what you have already tried

Comment: then fire a query get the result i assure you, you will definitely get

Comment: where Date>= '2/01/2012' AND Date<'2/28/2013' 
     AND CAST(Date AS TIME) BETWEEN '20:00' AND '08:00'      I am tried this

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
select *
from t
where hour(t.datetime + 4.0/24) between 0 and 11 and
      month(t.datetime + 4.0/24) = 2;
```

This is adding four hours to the date, under the assumption that you want 9 p.m. on Jan 31st to be included in February.  If you really want 1:00 a.m. on March 1st to be included, then subtract 20 hours:

```
select *
from t
where hour(t.datetime - 20.0/24) between 0 and 11 and
      month(t.datetime - 20.0/24) = 2;
```

BTW, you can also express the condition on the hour as:

```
where (hour(t.datetime) >= 20 or hour(t.datetime) < 8);
```

Comment: Actually the problem is not specific for month.I have  two dates.From date and To Date.Also i have two time fields.From time and to time.the date field is Datetime.I need to select data according to both date and time.My query selecting data between 13:00 to 15:00,But it is not suitable for 20:00 to 08:00.Pls give a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
...
WHERE(  DATEPART(month, DateCol) = 2
   AND( DATEPART(hour,  DateCol) >= 20 OR DATEPART(hour, DateCol) <= 8 )
OR  (   DATEPART(month, DateCol) = 3 
   AND  DATEPART(day,   DateCol) = 1
   AND  DATEPART(hour,  DateCol) <= 8));
```

Comment: Actually the problem is not specific for month.I have two dates.From date and To Date.Also i have two time fields.From time and to time.the date field is Datetime.I need to select data according to both date and time.My query selecting data between 13:00 to 15:00,But it is not suitable for 20:00 to 08:00.Pls give a solution for this